# Pig cross join and replace

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, apache-pig

I have two files. One file having the data as below

```
Ram,C,Bnglr
Shyam,A,Kolkata
```

The another file is having a reference

```
C,Calicut
A,Ahmedabad
```

Now using pig, I want to search and replace the data in the original file to create a new file ,so that I can create a new file using these two files.

```
Ram,Class,Bnglr
Shyam,Ahmedabad,Kolkata
```

Is it possible in pig. I know how to do that in MR but want to try out in pig.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.Join the files and select the required columns and write to the new file

```
A = LOAD 'file1.txt' AS (a1:chararray,a2:chararray,a3:chararray);
B = LOAD 'file2.txt' AS (b1:chararray,b2:chararray);
C = JOIN A BY a2, B BY b1;
D =  FOREACH C GENERATE A::a1,B::b2,A::a3;
STORE D INTO 'file3.txt'
```

Answer (score 0):

Above logic will work, but if you don't have matching records in second file in that case you will miss record from file1